# Snowflake: SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE output differs from GRANTS_TO_ROLES

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why do these two queries produce different result sets?

```
-- This query runs for < 1 second and results in 66 rows
SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE SOMEROLE ; 

-- This query runs for over 2 minutes and results in 61 rows
SELECT  *
FROM GRANTS_TO_ROLES 
WHERE GRANTEE_NAME  = 'SOMEROLE'
AND DELETED_ON  IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because they do different work, and have different data.

In a database like PostgreSQL all system/control data live in real actual tables. So looking at the system table gives you "how it really is".

Snowflake on the other hand, might be best considered "a data processing system" that pretends to be a "database". And as such at first the only way to get "system state" out of it was via SHOW command. At first you could not get the results into a table in any form. So it was all screen scraping to do stuff.

This work for our product, as we have our own files describing the DB shape, and we push our own changes. But it didn't work for other people, and slowly functions that allow indirect result processing like that of SHOW commands arrived. Then we started get materialized tables/views of SYSTEM_INFORMATION, but those all had "data can be N hour/minutes old" but where fast.

One way to consider this, is none of the data internally is "stored like a single consistent acid table" but is stored in ways that make "acting on the data to make data processing choices able to be done fast". And then as they are mapped into the metaphor of a table, they become slow, because there is a lot of hoop jumping.

Anyways as the product has evolved, the gaps between how something is done, and how people are used to it working elsewhere are not seamless. This point is trying to say in my opinion, it Snowflake doesn't do some on the tiny things that PostgreSQL nails well, but PostgreSQL doesn't process TB of data in a timely fashion. And I am after the later. But people often get a little shocked that creature comforts are missing. Well what a opinionated ramble.